# Webpack-dev-server doesn't pick up latest changes

Tags: webpack

This is my simple webpack.config.js. In order to load my application, I always have to do `yarn build` only then my application works and I can load it on the webpack-dev-server by doing `yarn start`

However when I make a change to my code webpack does print messages like

```
Version: webpack 4.41.5
Time: 143ms
Built at: 01/18/2020 2:12:27 PM
    Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  1.43 MiB    main  [emitted]  main
Entrypoint main = bundle.js
[./src/index.tsx] 1.43 KiB {main} [built]
    + 43 hidden modules
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

But it still shows old changes and new changes are not visible. I have to kill the webpack-dev-server and then do a `yarn build` manually and then again do `yarn start` and only then my changes are visible.

This is my webpack config

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    target: 'web',
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.tsx',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]        
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "."),
        port: 5000,
        watchContentBase: true,
        inline: true,
        hot: true
    }
}
```

I googled and I found 1000s of threads here and on GitHub. but nothing is helping me. Also those code files are wierd because webpack has changed very rapidly and most content on the internet is obsolete.

Comment: Show me folder structure ...

Comment: https://github.com/abhsrivastava/react-hooks

Comment: devServer: {
        ...
     writeToDisk: true

Comment: that works!!!! thank you so much