# How to make webpack-dev-server pick up latest changes

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm using Webpack 5 and cannot set dev-server to pick up the latest changes immediately. That's why when I have any changes in my project I should do `yarn build` first and then `yarn dev` every time. I've already seen the same question here [Webpack-dev-server doesn't pick up latest changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59805369/webpack-dev-server-doesnt-pick-up-latest-changes), but `writeToDisk: true` shows an error in the console. I've attached my webpack.config.js file.

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const miniCss = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: { main: './src/index.js' },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'main.js',
        publicPath: ''
    },
    mode: 'development',
    devServer: {
        static: {
            directory: path.join(__dirname, "dist")
        },
        compress: true,
        port: 8080,
        devMiddleware: {
            publicPath: "//localhost:8080",
        },
        hot: "only",
        open: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: '/node_modules/'
            },
            {
                test: /\.pug$/,
                loader: 'pug-loader',
                options: {
                    pretty: true
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, {
                    loader: 'css-loader'
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(s*)css$/,
                use: [
                    miniCss.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader',
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif|woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
                type: 'asset/resource'
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/pages/page/page.pug',
            filename: 'index.html'
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
        new miniCss(),
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is most likely with `hot: "only"`.  According to https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/ you will not see a page refresh on build failures if it's not `hot: true`.

Other than that I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code.  I suspect that if you change it to `hot: true` it should refresh the page and that you have some other build failure.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help, I changed hot: "only" to hot: true and it behaves the same way

Comment: Try adding ````contentBase```` to your static options, perhaps it's not watching because it doesn't know what contentBase to watch.  That's just a guess.

Comment: I've just tried and the console returns an error 'options object that does not match the API schema'